# hibernate.MappingException:Foreign key:category[CATEGORY_ID]))must'vesame numberof columns as thereferenced primarykey(category[STOCK_ID,CATEGORY_ID])

Tags: java, hibernate

I am really stuck in solving the below error. **Please help me to make it solve** ?

I'm developing ManyToMany relationship example.

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK302BCFEEB260666:category [CATEGORY_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (category [STOCK_ID,CATEGORY_ID])
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mkyong.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.mkyong.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK302BCFEEB260666:category [CATEGORY_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (category [STOCK_ID,CATEGORY_ID])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1829)
    at com.mkyong.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
```

The code I developed,
Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8833944947723156024L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String desc;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Stock> stocks = new HashSet<Stock>(0);

    public Category() { }

    public Category(String name, String desc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Category(String name, String desc, Set<Stock> stocks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.stocks = stocks;
    }
   // setters and getters
}
```

Stock.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock",uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7788035862084120942L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String stockName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "category", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")})
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>(0);

    public Stock() { }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName, Set<Category> categories) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.categories = categories;
    }

       // setters and getters
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

App.java

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hibernate many to many (Annotation)");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("PADINI");

        Category category1 = new Category("CONSUMER", "CONSUMER COMPANY");
        Category category2 = new Category("INVESTMENT", "INVESTMENT COMPANY");

        Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
        categories.add(category1);
        categories.add(category2);

        stock.setCategories(categories);

        session.save(stock);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Please help me what is wrong here?

```
create table stock(
   stock_id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   stock_code VARCHAR(50),
   stock_name VARCHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (`stock_id`)
);


create table Category(
   stock_id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   category_id VARCHAR(50),
   name VARCHAR(50),
   description VARCHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (`stock_id`)
)
```

**Edit-1:**
**Now I am getting below error?**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:31)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'test.stock_category' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2024)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> The name of the join table is assumed to be the table names of the
>   associated primary tables concatenated together (owning side first)
>   using an underscore.

In this case Join Table is stock_category

```
@JoinTable(name = "stock_category", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")})
```